# Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 on my code

Tags: java

This is my code. There is an error showing on the terminal window. It says java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at  top--; and   while (!stack.isEmpty()). Please help me solve this issue. I looked it up online but it did not help much. That is why I am asking you for help.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayStack<T> implements StackADT<T>
{
    private final static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;
    private int top;  
    private T[] stack;

    public ArrayStack()
    {
        this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    }    

    public ArrayStack(int initialCapacity)
    {
        top = 0;
        stack = (T[])(new Object[initialCapacity]);
    }    

    public void push(T element)
    {
        if (size() == stack.length) 
            expandCapacity();        
        stack[top] = element;
        top++;
    }    

    private void expandCapacity()
    {
        stack = Arrays.copyOf(stack, stack.length * 2);   
    }    

    public T pop() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");        
        top--;
        T result = stack[top];
        stack[top] = null; 

        return result;
    }

    public T peek() throws EmptyCollectionException
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");        
        return stack[top-1];
    }    

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
         return stack.length == 0;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return top;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayStack<Character> stack = new ArrayStack<Character>();
        String sentence = " ", word;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence:");
        sentence= in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Reversing each word:");
        Scanner sentenceScanner = new Scanner(sentence);
        while(sentenceScanner.hasNext())
        {
            word = sentenceScanner.next();
            for(int i= 0; i<word.length(); i++)        
            {
                stack.push(word.charAt(i));
            }

            while (!stack.isEmpty())   
            {
                System.out.print(stack.pop()); 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove unwanted comment in your code, it's difficult to read

Comment: Check your `isEmpty()`. Is it implemented correctly? What does `arrayType.length` do?

Comment: TIme to learn how to use your IDE's debugger.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran I am sorry. I removed the comments.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. I cannot figure out what the problem is with isEmpty()

Comment: The `length` property of array types is a constant that gives the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your isEmpty() and pop() functions do not work together. Think about this: when you decrement top and set the index to null does the actual size of the list get adjusted? The fix will come by changing isEmpty() I am just using pop() as an example.

Comment: How? Where do you change the size of the array? Setting an index location to null will not change the size of the array. Other than checking the size of the array, how could you implement isEmpty()? Hint: what is special about an empty stack?

Comment: I fixed the error. Instead of putting  return stack.length == 0;, I should have written return top ==0;

Comment: Correct, the special state that I was hinting at is that when the stack is empty the top is also the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Your `isEmpty()` method is implemented incorrectly.

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{
     return stack.length == 0;
}
```

It is currently comparing the size or capacity of of the `stack` array. This is a constant, it does not change. The value of

```
stack.length
```

is always equal to the value you used to initialize the array

```
new Object[length];
```

You should be comparing to the number of elements in your stack.

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{
     return top == 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3339580 Consider upvoting answers that helped and accepting the one that helped most.